# LaTeX Font Catalog Font

Tags: fonts

What font is used in the title for the LaTeX font catalog found here: http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/alphfonts.html .

Comment: Intelligent guess: Antiqua Bold.

Answer (score 1):

TeX Gyre Schola Bold, part of a family available from the [GUST e-Foundry](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/tex-gyre/schola)

[image]

Also on their site: scanned images of [many checks that Knuth](http://www.gust.org.pl/dek-checks) has written them for their work on TeX.